# How does the Argo Workflows CLI get permissions?

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows

I am new to the argo universe and was trying to set up Argo Workflows https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/docs/quick-start.md#install-argo-workflows .

I have installed the `argo` CLI from the page : https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/releases/latest . I was trying it in my minikube setup and I have my kubectl already configured to the minikube cluster. I am able to hit argo commands without any issues after putting it in my local bin folder.

How does it work? Where do the argo CLI is connecting to operate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `argo` CLI [manages two API clients](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/877d6569754be94f032e1c48d1f7226a83adfbec/cmd/argo/commands/get.go#L73-L74). The first client connects to the [Argo Workflows API](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/rest-api/) server. The second connects to the Kubernetes API. Depending on what you're doing, the CLI might connect just to one API or the other.

To connect to the Kubernetes API, the CLI just uses your kube config.

To connect to the Argo server, the CLI first checks for an `ARGO_TOKEN` environment variable. If it's not available, the CLI [falls back to using the kube config](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/877d6569754be94f032e1c48d1f7226a83adfbec/cmd/argo/commands/client/conn.go#L91).

`ARGO_TOKEN` is [only necessary when the Argo Server is configured to require client auth](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/rest-api/) and then only if you're doing things which require access to the Argo API instead of just the Kubernetes API.

Comment: Do argo CLI is meant to manage workflows only? I am new to Argo and I could see 4 different core projects under the umbrella.

Comment: Argo CD and Argo Workflows both have their own CLI. Argo Rollouts has a kubectl plugin. I'm not sure whether Argo Events has a CLI. There might be minor cross-applications of CLIs to other Argo projects, but I'm not aware of any major interaction.